# spring - java - query

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, webserver

I have a website which has some information specific to versions and their vulnerabilities. eg: Tomcat - their versions (2.3,2.5,2.7 etc. ) and their information.

Lets say I don't want to click on specific version and then get the result but I want to pass a text file with the application names and versions - I want to write a code which reads this text file and gives me the output only with the application and version names I have sent as an input in the text file. I am new to Spring.

Hoping you guys will guide me and also suggest me some links which would help in understanding how to proceed.

Comment: So you want code to upload the file and read it in Java?

Comment: Yeah so I want to read the file dynamically and then send a request with the details in the file and with those details it should open the website information no need to upload it

Comment: So I have a text file which has name eg: Apache Tomcat and it’s version eg: 3.0 so the file looks like this     “Apache Tomcat” “3.0”                                        
                  “JBoss”  “4.3”              
Now I want to read this text file and fetch the data according to the file name and Version number . There is a xyz website which has  multiple names and version numbers with some information projected. I want to read the text file and project the data automatically rather than typing Apache and then clicking on version number on the website .

Comment: I would need much more information than this to help you out. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have mentioned it above @Aniket Sahrawat

Comment: That is not going to cut it. You will need to explain exactly. You can not just go "I want this done" without any context of what is going on underneath.

Comment: It is not as simple as printing hello world to the console. There is absolutely no information that can help us direct you. For eg: what is inside your pom? what controller presents this information? So in essence, this question is vague.

Comment: I have already done the web page which accepts the user inputs like component name and component version So when I give the input it will fetch the data with some information for example vulnerabilities are 33 etc.. Now what I want to do is I want to read a text file which will have the component name and version number given in the text file.     
I have to pass this text file so that my code can read it and when I hit the server with http:localhost/8080 it should automatically  fetch the data with whatever name and version number I have given in the text file .

Comment: I have searched online but not able to come up to with a solution on how to read a file and fetch the data when I hit the API and also whatever data is fetched I want to get the output data in text format